# Searching for Duplicates in SQL Table with Confidence Score

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a SQL Server 2016 stored procedure that is evaluating data looking for duplicates. Since not all data is present, missing columns are blank (''), not NULL. I compare the data and give a confidence score.

It works for the most part, however, it doesn't process any of the entries with a blank company. It should process the blank company just like any other and I am not sure why it isn't.

```
SELECT 
    ranking AS score,
    RankMapping.description AS code,
    'CUST' AS tablename,
    Duplicate.uid AS tableID, 
    originalCustNo
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         FirstCompany.uid AS originalCustNo, 
         Duplicate.*, 
         CASE WHEN FirstCompany.uid = Duplicate.uid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
            + CASE WHEN FirstCompany.company = Duplicate.company THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
            + CASE WHEN FirstCompany.fname = Duplicate.fname AND FirstCompany.lname = Duplicate.lname THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
            + CASE WHEN FirstCompany.add1 = Duplicate.add1  AND FirstCompany.city = Duplicate.city THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            + CASE WHEN FirstCompany.phone1 = Duplicate.phone1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            + CASE WHEN FirstCompany.email = Duplicate.email THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            AS ranking
        FROM 
            (SELECT uid, company, fname, lname, add1, city, phone1, email
             FROM 
                 (SELECT 
                      uid, company, fname, lname, add1, city, phone1, email,
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY uid) AS ordering
                  FROM #tmpCoreData) FC
             WHERE 
                 ordering = 1) AS  FirstCompany
        JOIN 
            #tmpCoreData Duplicate ON Duplicate.uid >= FirstCompany.uid
                                   AND Duplicate.company = FirstCompany.company) Duplicate
            JOIN (VALUES 
                (6, 'Original'),
                (5, 'Duplicate'),
                (4, 'Duplicate'),
                (3, 'Likely Dupe'),
                (2, 'Possible Dupe'),
                (1, 'Not Likely Dupe'),
                (0, 'Individual')
  ) RankMapping(score, description) ON RankMapping.score = Duplicate.ranking
ORDER BY 
    Duplicate.originalCustNo, Duplicate.ranking DESC
```

I put my data table and code into [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/16380/1)

I'd appreciate some fresh eyes!

Thanks!

Comment: At a glance - you're joining on `duplicate.company = FirstCompany.company` which would likely remove blanks from the results.  Do you need that join condition?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what *you* mean by "duplicates" would all help.  Frankly, I have no idea what the query has to do with the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Check out the SQL Fiddle link, it has sample data and if you run it, you can see the results (minus the blank companies).

Comment: @AaronDietz That was it, I don't know WTF I was thinking.  This is why I needed fresh eyes! :D

Comment: @Dizzy49 Been there myself, glad it was an easy fix :)